# Unity use script with the input fields

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have a PHP script and a .cs script which is basically a login/user. But I want to use it with the fields in the app and not custom made ones with the code.

Here is a image of what im talking about

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgofB.png)

here is my .cs code

```
  if (register)
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Username");
            user = GUILayout.TextField(user);
            GUILayout.Label("Name");
            name = GUILayout.TextField(name);
            GUILayout.Label("password");
            password = GUILayout.PasswordField(password, "*"[0]);
            GUILayout.Label("Re-password");
            rePass = GUILayout.PasswordField(rePass, "*"[0]);

            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if (GUILayout.Button("Back"))
                register = false;

            if (GUILayout.Button("Register"))
            {
                message = "";

                if (user == "" || name == "" || password == "")
                    message += "Please enter all the fields \n";
                else
                {
                    if (password == rePass)
                    {
                        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
                        form.AddField("user", user);
                        form.AddField("name", name);
                        form.AddField("password", password);
                        WWW w = new WWW("http://dri********.com/register.php", form);
                        StartCoroutine(registerFunc(w));
                    }
                    else
                        message += "Your Password does not match \n";
                }
            }

            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
```

So right now its displaying new boxes but I want it to use my current inputfields that are in my design

Answer (score 1):

GUILayout in code creates those fields at runtime, you will need to get rid of them.

In a new class maybe,attached to a gameobject in the inspector:

```
//Add a namespace 
using UnityEngine.UI;
// few public fields that represent the ui textboxes e.g
public Text name;
// user will now be
string user = name.text;
```

You can pass now pass these variables as arguments to your register class, or put it all in the same class. your choice.

Comment: Essentially...stop using `OnGui`